# Timeout NGINX + php-fpm

Tags: nginx, timeout

Стоит nginx + php-fpm. На сайте используется long poll технология, проблема в том, что с человека идет ajax запрос, который ожидает, когда ему ответит сервер, т.е он может висеть и 2 часа и 4 часа. Как установить бесконечный таймаут на сервере, что бы long poll запросы работали корректно. В данный момент при запуске сайта сервер работает, пока какой-либо запрос не уйдет в таймаут, после сервер становится недоступен.

Comment: а зачем так долго? может быть стоит хотя бы раз в несколько минут отвечать что ничего нового не случилось? Тогда будет еще один запрос, потом еще один и т.д., т.е. timeout'ы не страшны

Comment: Сейчас переписываю все под вебсокеты, но все равно хотелось бы определиться с проблемой.

Comment: long polling и php не очень удачное сочетание – будет висеть по процессу php на каждого подключённого клиента.

Comment: @Sergiks вас php-fpm не смутил?